# Solving for the positions of vertices of 3 line segments

Tags: geometry, computer-science, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have 3 line segments of lengths p,q,r joined at their ends. Let's call the vertices A, B, C, and D. Suppose D is fixed at the origin. Suppose that A is constrained to move only in the Y direction. Finally, suppose that segments q and r are joined at point C and segments p and q are joined at point B. Thus, there are 3 line segments which are joined at their end points. One end is free to move and the other end is constrained. Please see the attached diagram:

[image: 3 line segments joined] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyfZL.png))

I would like to solve for the (x,y) positions of point B and C given a known displacement of point A in the y-dimension.

I have already done this in rectangular coordinates to get 4 equations in 4 variables (Bx,By,Cx,Cy). To solve the position requires solving the system of 4 nonlinear equations.

(1) Would this get simpler in polar coordinates? I'm rusty.

(2) Can anyone provide information on computer algorithms to solve this problem?

Comment: In general, you won't have a unique solution: given the position of $A$ several different positions of $B$ and $C$ are possible.

Comment: @Aretino, yes but I don't believe there will be infinite solutions. There should just be 2 which are mirror images of each other. 

edit: nope, that's wrong now that I look at it again. How do you solve for the solution space? there are more constraints I can put on it for my application. Such as, B can only travel in +x direction. C can only travel in -x direction, and has a maximum negative x displacement.

Comment: @Aretino also A has a max y displacement and at Ay_max, By=Cy. I still don't think these constraints get you to a single solution but if I could find a way to solve the positions I could start applying the constraints as well.

Comment: There is a continuum of allowed positions, see here: http://tube.geogebra.org/m/2550191

Comment: @user308907 I finished my answer. Please check it while I continue with finishing the cat toilet. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\angle BAD=\theta$, so that $x_B=p\sin\theta$ and $y_B=y_A-p\cos\theta$. Point $C$ can be found as the intersection of the circles having centers at $B$ and $D$ and radii $q$ and $r$ respectively: its coordinates (if they exist) are the solutions of the system
$$
\left\{\eqalign
{(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2&=q^2\\
x^2+y^2&=r^2
}\right.
$$
In general, for a given value of $\theta$ you'll get two possible positions of $C$ (if $BD<q+r$), or none at all (if $BD>q+r$).

Comment: I found your idea of using an interactive GeoGebra worksheet here very helpful. I built on it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is just about geometrical constraints, no physical complications like inertia.

We have the position vectors:
\begin{align}
r_A &= (0, y_A) \\
r_B &= (x_B, y_B) \\
r_C &= (x_C, y_C) \\
r_D &= (0, 0) \\
\end{align}
and these constraint equations:
\begin{align}
p^2 &= \lVert r_B - r_A \rVert^2 = x_B^2 + (y_B - y_A)^2 \\
q^2 &= \lVert r_C - r_B \rVert^2 = (x_C-x_B)^2 + (y_C - y_B)^2 \quad (*) \\
s^2 &= \lVert r_D - r_C \rVert^2 = x_C^2 + y_C^2
\end{align}
So we have these unknowns
$$
x_B, y_B, x_C, y_C
$$
as $y_A$ is given.

Here is a possible parametrization via $(y_A, \varphi)$:

$$
r_B = (x_B, y_B) = (p \sin\varphi, y_A - p \cos\varphi)
$$

The feasible coordintes for $r_C$ are taken from the intersection
of the two circles for $q$ and $s$ segments, see equations $(*)$.

[Interactive Web GeoGebra Worksheet](http://ggbtu.be/m2550791)

[image: 3 chain] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM11A.png))

To the right, there are controls to choose the three segment lengths $p, q, s$:

- The $\color{red}{\text{red circle}}$ includes the area where the $p$
  segment is allowed,
- similar a $\color{cyan}{\text{cyan coloured
     circle}}$ for the $q$ segment and
- the $\color{green}{\text{green circle}}$ for the $s$ segment.

These lengths go into the constraint equations $(*)$ given above.

The possible configuration is influenced by the two parameters:

- The $y$ coordinate of the point $A$, $y_a$ which is visualized as a
  $\color{red}{\text{purple segment}}$ on the $y$-axis.
- Then we have the $\color{olive}{\text{olive coloured angle } \varphi}$ which can be used to choose all positions for point $B$.

Further we can see the point $D$ which is fixed at the origin $(0,0)$.

So the only point whose positions is determined from the above is the position of the point $C$.

The above image shows a configuration where the 
$\color{cyan}{\text{cyan coloured circle}}$ for the middle $q$ segment does not intersect with the
$\color{green}{\text{green coloured circle}}$ of the lower $s$ segment.
It is not a feasble solution for the constraints.

[image: one intersection point] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsA0T.png))

[image: two intersecion points] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFNnS.png))

This intersection is the set of feasible positions for the point $C$:

- It can be empty (no solution for $C$) or
- can contain one point (unique solution for $C$, see first image above),
- two points (two solutions for $C$, see second image above) and
- for a rare but existing configuration consisting of the points of the full circle, if both circles have same radius and center (infinite many solutions for $C$, see image below).

[image: infinite many intersection points] ([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLJ4W.png))

I suggest to use the above link for the interactive GeoGebra worksheet and play a bit with the values to get a feeling.